# Problems with dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a simple chart that displays the name, carbohydrates and type of cereal on a dataset. 
Despite, following the instructions on some website, some error comes up reading "# take() does not accept boolean indexers" which I don't know how to interpret. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

pd.read_csv('.\cereal.csv', sep= ',')

cereal = pd.read_csv('.\cereal.csv', sep= '\t')

cereal.duplicated()

cereal.columns

carbs = cereal[['name','carbo',]]
```

The error results from the last cell.

Apologies if I've been unclear.

Edit: 
The following is the error trace.

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-058914a7338a> in <module>
----> 1 carbs = cereal[['name','carbo',]]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2984             if is_iterator(key):
   2985                 key = list(key)
-> 2986             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
   2987 
   2988         # take() does not accept boolean indexers
```

name and carbo are indeed names.

Comment: can you print `cereal.columns` and see if `'name'` and `'carbs'` exist ? also your calling a few methods but not assinging them to anything, your calling `pd.read_csv` twice, is there a reason for that ?

Comment: please share the error stacktrace as well.

Comment: @Datanovice unfortunately I don't really know what you mean by calling pd.read_csv. I put it in a variable so that I could manipulate it more.